# Центрирование контента внутри css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Прошу вашей помощи, как мне центрировать контент 'Vintage Oliva' (белый блок)? Использую css grid для создания верстки, при увеличении размера монитора заметно, что весь контент в этом блоке прижимается к верху. Заранее спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 <!-- Vintage grid -->

    <div class="block-grid">
        <div class="image-bicycle-vintage">
           <div class="bicycle-company-logo"></div>
            <img src="images/Layer-101.png">
        </div>
        <div class="block-vintage-oliva">
            <div class="content-vintage-oliva">
                <div class="image-vintage-oliva"></div>
                <h1>Vintage Oliva</h1>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived.</p>
                <div class="border"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="image-bicycle-third">
                <img src="images/Layer-11.png">
            </div>
    </div>



 /*-------------grid vintage--------------*/

.block-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax (400px, auto) minmax (200px, auto);
}

.block-grid > .image-bicycle-vintage > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.image-bicycle-vintage > .bicycle-company-logo {
    background: url(images/Logo-bicycle-company.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 113px;
    height: 118px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.image-bicycle-vintage {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    background: #282f35;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.block-vintage-oliva {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.content-vintage-oliva {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 82%;
}

.image-vintage-oliva {
    background: url(images/Icon1.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 41px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.block-vintage-oliva h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #353738;
    padding: 30px 0 25px;
}

.block-vintage-oliva p {
    color: #848789;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Lato Regular';
    line-height: 31px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #848789;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 44px auto 54px auto;
    color: #848789;
}

.image-bicycle-third {
    background: #353738;
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    height: 100%;
}

.image-bicycle-third > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout#%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8  По простому говоря, там `align-items` и `align-self` как в `flexbox` работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно с помощью flexbox.

```
.content-vintage-oliva {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```